# Get Android view as Bitmap to save it on SD

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap, android-canvas

I'm trying to save the path that is being drawn on a View but I just can't figure out how to do this.

Here is what I'm doing in my Activity to create the View and set it as content:

```
View accPathView = new AccPathView(this, steps);
setContentView(accPathView);
```

Then in the onDraw method of my View class, I'm simply creating a path and drawing it on the canvas I received as parameter:

But then, when I try to get the bitmap of my view with getDrawingCache(), it's always null and creates an empty image on my SD. I tried

```
accPathView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
accPathView.buildDrawingCache(true);
```

Unfortunately it didn't change anything and I still get an empty bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null)
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

EDIT:

How do you the above method?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View accPathView = new AccPathView(this, steps);
    setContentView(accPathView);

    accPathView.post(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             Bitmap viewBitmap = getBitmapFromView(accPathView);
         }
    });

    // your remaining oncreate

}
```

Comment: Where would you call it? In the onCreate after the setContentView ?

Comment: Thank you, it now works perfectly with the edited answer!